# How to use HTML const variables in the script in pugjs

Tags: pug

```
-
    const welcomeModalData = [ 
    { 
        title: "Stay on top of your health with timely reminders", 
        description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet." 
    }, 
    { 
        title: "Stay on top of your health with timely reminders", 
        description: "Get a personalized cost estimate..." 
    } 
    ]

p#title #{welcomeModalData[0].title} 
p#description #{welcomeModalData[0].description}
    
script. 
    document.getElementById("title").textContent = ${welcomeModalData[1].title}; // not working
    document.getElementById("description").textContent = ${welcomeModalData[1].description}; //not working
```

I am going to change the text as JSON data value in script using pugjs. But I don't know how to use the JSON data in script. I have tried these methods until now but can't solve.

```
${welcomeModalData}
#{welcomeModalData}
JSON.parse(welcomeModalData)
json.stringfy(welcomeModalData)
...
```

Anybody, could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You are using [plain text](https://pugjs.org/language/plain-text.html) in the `script` tag. From the linked page:

> Plain text does still use tag and string [interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html).

So this should work (it does on my machine):

```
script.
  document.getElementById("title").textContent = "#{welcomeModalData[1].title}";
  document.getElementById("description").textContent = "#{welcomeModalData[1].description}";
```

The unminified result is:

```html
<script>
document.getElementById("title").textContent = "Stay on top of your health with timely reminders";
document.getElementById("description").textContent = "Get a personalized cost estimate...";
</script>
```

I.e. use `#{myVariable}`. Remember the quotes. Single quotes are also ok.

If it's possible that the variables are multiline text, you can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) because they support multiline text:

```
-
  const myVariable = `
    Look ma,
    I'm a multiline string!
  `

script.
  document.getElementById("title").textContent = `#{myVariable}`;
```

Unminified result:

```html
<script>
document.getElementById("title").textContent = `
  Look ma,
  I'm a multiline string!
`;
</script>
```

---

About your comment:

> And also if I use index?
> ex: `var index = 1; featureTitle.textContent = "#{welcomeModalData[index].title}";`
> but this is wrong

If you mean something like this, it can't be done:

```
script.
  const index = 1;
  document.getElementById("title").textContent = "#{welcomeModalData[index].title}";
  document.getElementById("description").textContent = "#{welcomeModalData[index].description}";
```

It won't work because the first line (`const index = 1;`) is just *plain text* like the rest of the `script` tag's content (excluding the interpolations). You can't mix Pug variables and the printed JS variables.

You can, however, make `index` a "Pug variable" and use it in the interpolations:

```
-
  const welcomeModalData = [
    // ...
  ]
  const index = 1;

script.
  document.getElementById("title").textContent = "#{welcomeModalData[index].title}";
  document.getElementById("description").textContent = "#{welcomeModalData[index].description}";
```

I don't know what you are doing, but this all feels quite fragile.

Comment: Thank you. And also if I use index? ex: var index = 1; featureTitle.textContent = "#{welcomeModalData[index].title}"; but this is wrong, could you help me?

Comment: I updated my answer with a reply to your question.

Comment: Thank you, I understood your description. Now, I want to make this:
When clicking the button, the index value is increased and I am going to change the text using the index.code:  index += 1; featureTitle.textContent = "#{welcomeModalData[index].title}";

Comment: That's a different question, so you should open a new, separate question (after first trying to solve the problem yourself). If I have answered your original question, please accept my answer (see [_What should I do when someone answers my question?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)) and move on to the new, separate question.

Comment: Okay, Good. Thank you.
I have accepted your answer, but my reputation is less than 15 yet.

Comment: Hi @mts knn, I have opened a new question regarding the pugjs variable. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65788841/how-to-make-previous-and-next-button-works-in-pugjs   can you help me again? Thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't think you need 15 reputation to accept an answer. It's not the same as upvoting an answer. See [_How does accepting an answer work?_](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Of course, I mean that votes cast by those with less than 15 reputations are recorded but do not change the publicly displayed post score. So I have accepted your answer already, but you can't see that. Could you accept my question?